# Accessing API JSON response value

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nodes

I've got this json object via an API.

```
var servers = {   
    'd22ab1': { 
        condition: 'autorebooted',
        name: 'acb1'
    },
    '6946e0': { 
        condition: 'online',
        name: 'abc2'
    }
}

for (var server in servers) {
    console.log(server.condition);
}
```

I'm trying to get the condition value but my for loop doesn't work as i expected. what am I missing? Thank you!!!

Comment: looks like you wanted a `for...of` loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to access via `server` key as you iterate over keys.

```js
var servers = {   
    'd22ab1': { 
        condition: 'autorebooted',
        name: 'acb1'
    },
    '6946e0': { 
        condition: 'online',
        name: 'abc2'
    }
}

for (var server in servers) {
    console.log(servers[server].condition);
}
```

Or you can use `Object.values`, which returns values of each property.

```js
var servers = {   
    'd22ab1': { 
        condition: 'autorebooted',
        name: 'acb1'
    },
    '6946e0': { 
        condition: 'online',
        name: 'abc2'
    }
}

Object.values(servers).forEach(item => console.log(item.condition));
```

Comment: Thank you Suren! Your suggestion worked the perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

`servers` is not iterable, use `Object.values`

```
Object.values( servers ).forEach( s => console.log( s.condition ) )
```

**Demo**

```js
var servers = {   
    'd22ab1': { 
        condition: 'autorebooted',
        name: 'acb1'
    },
    '6946e0': { 
        condition: 'online',
        name: 'abc2'
    }
};
Object.values( servers ).forEach( s => console.log( s.condition ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Object.keys on server to get all the keys. Then iterate over the keys and get conditions from each.

```js
var servers = {   
    'd22ab1': { 
        condition: 'autorebooted',
        name: 'acb1'
    },
    '6946e0': { 
        condition: 'online',
        name: 'abc2'
    }
}
let conditions = Object.keys(servers).map(key => servers[key].condition);

console.log(conditions)
```